# How to setup guicorn command to start django q

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

Hello i have my app uploaded on digitalocean server. Whenever i upload it i use gunicorn command to start my app. Currently it looks like this:

`gunicorn reservationSystem.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm`

My question is how to update it to start django-q service as well.

I think this may be cause for my app to crash. After last update (it included django-q for the first time) it crashes whenever i try to open it. Because of that i suspect that the reason for app crashing is that django-q is not started. Just in case you notice something wrong here is my q_cluster setup:

```
Q_CLUSTER = {
    'orm': 'default',  # should use django's ORM and database as a broker.
    'workers': 4,
    'timeout': 30,
    'retry': 60,
    'queue_limit': 50,
    'bulk': 10,
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can update this command:

```
gunicorn reservationSystem.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm
```

into this:

```
gunicorn reservationSystem.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm && python manage.py qcluster
```

I added `&& python manage.py qcluster` at the end of the command.